# MFC Crash on repeated SetWindowText() when a background color for the dialog is specified

Tags: mfc, dialog, crash, background-color

The following code works fine:

> for(int i=0; i<500; i++) {
>    for(int j=0; j<100; j++) {
>     m_title.SetWindowText(_T("lol"));
>    }
>   }

But when I set a background color for the dialog:

> HBRUSH CTaggingDlg::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor) {
>    return CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,0,0));//BLACK
>   }

The loop above causes the program to hit a breakpoint in wingdi.cpp at:

> CPaintDC::CPaintDC(CWnd* pWnd)

How do I set a background color for the dialog without having it crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. By changing the way I set the background color to the method in this article:

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-d/dislog/background/article.php/c1895

The problem has been resolved.

Comment: It'll be because you were leaking brushes (CreateSolidBrush gives you a new brush each time). By using a CBrush as a member variable, you only have one brush object, and it's cleaned up along with the window.